# Meteor Autoform doesn't update the collection

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have problem where my update and update-pushArray doesn't really update or add something to my array.

My template is this:

```
<template name="PersonShow">
<div class="container">
    <div class="user-data">
        <h2>{{name}}</h2>
        {{> quickForm id="PersonShow" type="update" collection="Registry" doc=this fields="isActiveEmployee"}}
    </div>
    <div class="device-data">
        {{#each device}}
        <h3><p>Device: {{type}}</p></h3>
        <h3><p>Quantity: {{quantity}}</p></h3>
        {{#autoForm id="PersonShow" type="update" collection="Registry" doc=this}}
        {{> afQuickField name="device.0.isInUse"}}
        {{> afQuickField name="comment"}}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        {{/autoForm}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    <div class="add-new-device">
        {{> quickForm id="PersonShow" type="update-pushArray" collection="Registry" doc=this scope="device"}}
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

and my collections:

```
Registry = new Mongo.Collection("registry");

Registry.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    label: "First and lastname",
    max: 200,
    optional: false
  },
  device: {
    type: Array,
    optional: true
  },
  'device.$': {
    type: Object
  },
  'device.$.type': {
    type: String
  },
  'device.$.isInUse': {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
      options: [
        {label: "Yes", value: "Yes"},
        {label: "No", value: "No"}
        ]
    }
  },
  'device.$.serialNumber': {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  'device.$.quantity': {
    type: Number,
    min: 0
  },
  isActiveEmployee: {
    type: String,
    optional: false,
    autoform: {
      options: [
        {label: "Yes", value: "Yes"},
        {label: "No", value: "No"}
        ]
    }
  },
  comment: {
    type: String,
    label: "Comments",
    optional: true,
    max: 1000
  },
}));
```

Nothing really happens when I press the update/update-pushArray, nothing gets sent to collection.

Update works if I do it like this:

`{{> afQuickField name="device"}}` but I only want to update one specific field in my array.

Also for update-pushArray I want to add things to my array `device`

Can anybody see whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was related to the templates. When I put each form to different template, the problem was solved.

Comment: Can you paste your routes code, how you sent the data from routes to the form? I mean at `doc=this`.
I'm asking this since I have a problem with retrieving data and showing them up in the fields to update.
[My unsolved question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936485/unable-to-get-data-into-the-form-fields-to-update-the-values-meteor-autoform)